# Regular expression to find one character that is preceeded by an even number of the same character

Tags: regex

I am trying to match an input string which might have single quote character ('). My challenge is, I need to ignore any even number of the quote characters that preceed the target character, since they are considered the escaping characters.

The following is what I have come up.

```
(?=('')*)'
```

However this doesn't work for the purpose yet. For instance, if I have an input of `'''`, the regular expression will match all three single quote characters, instead of just the last one.

Here are some samples.

```
'             ## match
''            ## no-match
'''           ## matches the last quote character
''''          ## no-match
abc'          ## matches the last quote character
Mike''s home' ## matches the last quote character only
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For your first desired regex, would you put some examples?

Comment: Sure, just added some samples.

Comment: Tnx, added my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what environment you use for testing Regular Expressions however below regex is **PCRE** compatible which works per as your given examples:

```
(?<!')(?:'')*\K'(?!')
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/hP1iE6)**

Comment: Thanks @revo, this is probably the closest. I am using .NET, which doesn't seem to recognize \K sequence. Your demo does produce the exact result that I am looking for. I use Regex Tester on http://www.regexlib.com to run my tests.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it appears that you want to **detect an input that contains at least one sequence of an odd number of single-quote characters**.

Here is a regex that I believe will satisfy this requirement:

```
(^'|[^']')('')*([^']|$)
```

Or, the equivalent that simply adds `?:` to suppress the capture groups:

```
(?:^'|[^']')(?:'')*(?:[^']|$)
```

I have written a Perl program to test this regex against the sample data you provided. (And I added some additional sample inputs as well.) Please see the following for the expected output from the program as well as the program itself.

**Expected Output:**

```
* [']
* [x']
  [x'']
* [x''']
  ['']
* [''x']
  [''x'']
  [''x''y]
* [''']
  ['''']
  [''''x]
* [abc ']
* [Mike''s home']
  [Mike''s home'']
* [Mike''s home''']
* [Mike''s home'''x]
  [Mike''s home'''']
  [Mike''s home''''x]
```

**Perl Program to Demonstrate RegEx:**

```perl
#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $match = "  ";

    if (/(^'|[^']')('')*([^']|$)/) {

#         ^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^ ^
#        (1a) (1b)  (2)   3a  3b
#
# Match the line if:
# (1a) The line begins with a single quote character
#      -or-
# (1b) Somewhere contains a non-quote character followed by a single
#      quote character
# (2)  That is optionally followed by an even number of quote characters.
# (3a) And that is followed by a non-quote character
#      -or-
# (3b) The end of the line.

        $match = "* "
    }

    print "$match\[$_\]\n";
}

__END__
'
x'
x''
x'''
''
''x'
''x''
''x''y
'''
''''
''''x
abc '
Mike''s home'
Mike''s home''
Mike''s home'''
Mike''s home'''x
Mike''s home''''
Mike''s home''''x
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidRR, very close, but when I have an input of `'''`, the expression matches the entire string instead of just last character.

Comment: Try `(^(?:'')*|[^'](?:'')*)(')([^']|$)` . You should find the single quote in `$2` for all inputs. If this is satisfactory to you, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidRR, I can't go with $2 approach, since I am passing to a general library that expects one match which has to be the last quote character.

Comment: OK, I've revised the regex to return the single quote of interest in `$1`. Here it is: `(?:^(?:'')*|[^'](?:'')*)(')(?:[^']|$)` . There are no other capture groups.

Comment: Thanks again. This still matches the entire string when the input is `'''`. I mean I can't use $1 either.

Answer (score 1):

With .net you can use a variable length lookbehind:

To find the last quote preceded by an even number of quotes in general:

```
(?<=^(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*)'(?=[^']*$)
```

*(you only need to anchor the subpattern inside the lookbehind at the begining of the string and to check there is no more quotes until the end with a lookahead.)*

For the particular case where you only need to match an unescaped quote, you can simply use:

```
(?<=(?<!')(?:'')*)'(?!')
```

*(In this case, no need to "count" from the start of the string and to check the string until the end, you only need to check contiguous characters.)*

or the same without nested lookbehinds:

```
(?<=(?:^|[^'])(?:'')*)'(?!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to leverage negative look-ahead and look-behind, but bear in mind they don't work the same in all implementations (and I honestly don't know the details, I just know that's true):

```
(?<!')'(?!')
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iCFtMf_vaPY9b5LY)

Comment: Thanks Michael for the quick response! It doesn't seem the regular expression is matching the last character of '''.

Comment: I just made a little modification based on what you have suggested. I now have (?=('')*)'(?!'), it seems to be working now. Oops, just realized that it doesn't seem to work properly for the second test case that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:'')*(.+)
```

The first bit `(?:'')*` is a non-capturing group with the second set of parentheses returning the match

See [demo here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YKVxblspKno2WE43)

Comment: Thanks @garyh, that doesn't 100% work, I want to capture only the last quote character.